# CP210x assigned with /dev/ttyUSB0, How to know device name in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, module

I want to know device name with C++.
my CP210x device is assigned with /dev/ttyUSB0 with this driver.
http://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/USBtoUARTBridgeVCPDrivers.aspx

from my C++ device, I want to know device name ( like /dev/ttyUSB0, /dev/ttyUSB1 ... ) 
because I have 3 device...
I want to distinguish device.

1/
First, I tried libusb
but It maybe not enough...

```
libusb_context *context = NULL;
    libusb_device **list = NULL;
    int rc = 0;
    ssize_t count = 0;
    uint8_t path[8];


    rc = libusb_init(&context);
    assert(rc == 0);

    count = libusb_get_device_list(context, &list);
    assert(count > 0);

    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < count; ++idx) {
        libusb_device *device = list[idx];
        libusb_device_descriptor desc = {0};

        rc = libusb_get_device_descriptor(device, &desc);


        assert(rc == 0);

        printf("Vendor:Device = %04x:%04x:%d\n", desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct, desc.bcdUSB);
        //printf("Vendor:Device = %d:%d:%d:%d\n", desc.bDeviceClass, desc.bcdDevice, desc.iSerialNumber, desc.iProduct);
        printf("%04x:%04x (bus %d, device %d) ",
                                desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct,
                                libusb_get_bus_number(device), libusb_get_device_address(device)); //, device->filename);


        rc = libusb_get_port_numbers(device,path,sizeof(path));
        if (rc > 0) {
             printf(" path: %d", path[0]);
             for (int j = 1; j < rc; j++){
                     printf(".%d", path[j]);
             }
             printf("\n");
        }
        //desc.bcdUSB
    }
```

it return

```
Vendor:Device = 1d6b:0002:512
1d6b:0002 (bus 2, device 1) Vendor:Device = 1d6b:0001:272
1d6b:0001 (bus 8, device 1) Vendor:Device = 1d6b:0001:272
1d6b:0001 (bus 7, device 1) Vendor:Device = 1d6b:0001:272
1d6b:0001 (bus 6, device 1) Vendor:Device = 1d6b:0002:512
1d6b:0002 (bus 1, device 1) Vendor:Device = 1d6b:0001:272
1d6b:0001 (bus 5, device 1) Vendor:Device = 10c4:ea60:272
10c4:ea60 (bus 4, device 10)  path: 2
Vendor:Device = 1d6b:0001:272
1d6b:0001 (bus 4, device 1) Vendor:Device = 1d6b:0001:272
1d6b:0001 (bus 3, device 1)
```

Is there any way to know assigned device name by kernel module ?

Answer (score 1):

finally, I resolve this.. Thank you all !
I use shell script . I call it from my C++ programming.

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                         
echo password | sudo -S cat /proc/tty/driver/usbserial | grep cp210x  | awk -F'[ :]' '{print "/dev/ttyUSB"$1" "$8" "$10}'
```

Output is here.

```
/dev/ttyUSB0 10c4 ea60
```